# javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException: No provider for ${mail.protocol}

Tags: java, spring

I want to send mail to reset password for users if he forgot his password i get this error:

> org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Mail server connection
>   failed; nested exception is javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException: No
>   provider for ${mail.protocol}. Failed messages:
>   javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException: No provider for ${mail.protocol};
>   message exception details (1) are:

and this is my `MailConfiguration.java`;

```
public class MailConfiguration {

@Value("${mail.protocol}")
private String protocol;

@Value("${mail.host}")
private String host;

@Value("${mail.from}")
private String from;

@Value("${mail.username}")
private String username;

@Value("${mail.password}")
private String password;


@Bean
public JavaMailSender javaMailSender() {
    JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
    Properties mailProperties = new Properties();
    mailProperties.put(false, auth);
    mailProperties.put(false, starttls);
    mailSender.setJavaMailProperties(mailProperties);
    mailSender.setHost(host);
    mailSender.setPort(465);
    mailSender.setProtocol(protocol);
    mailSender.setUsername(username);
    mailSender.setPassword(password);
    return mailSender;
}
}
```

this is my EmailConfig.properties:

```
mail.protocol=smtp
mail.host=localhost
mail.port=465
mail.smtp.auth=false
mail.smtp.starttls.enable=false
mail.from=me@localhost
mail.username=   
mail.password=
```

any help Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It seems, that you have not properly connected your EmailConfig.properties, because mailProtocol is not read from it.

Make sure you have @PropertySource somewhere in your config classes with valid path to your properties file(i.e. "classpath:EmailConfig.properties")

Comment: it 's right, there is a problem in my EmailConfig.properties so i modify that without using the file EmailConfig.properties but i get this error:   java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect. Failed messages: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: localhost, port: 465;

Comment: Do you have your own local smtp host running on localhost? In case you do not, there might be a problem. You should provide a valid smtp host in mail.host and mail.port properties. Real smtp could be i.e. gmail SMTP(host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 587). To simulate local SMTP you could try [Postfix](http://www.postfix.org) (Linux or OSX) or [hMailServer](https://www.hmailserver.com) (Windows OS)

Comment: thanks really it helps me your notes but now i have this error: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials n89sm6656812wmi.33 - gsmtp

Comment: You need to disable auth: `mailProperties.put("mail.smtp.auth", false);`, if you do not want to use any credentials.

Comment: I'm sorry for this question: but the username and password of what i should set??

Comment: username is mail where you are sending from and password is simply a password for this mail account :)

Comment: ok really thankful and that's work for me. my problem now when i click in the link in my mail : http://localhost/reset?token=d15d5849-b5ea-4835-b4e0-9f60445c692b it return : This site is inaccessible . there's any example or blog using (mail, spring and angular)  to reset password.

Comment: Do you have your spring web application running under localhost with standard port(80) with web root servlet with path "/" and controller with "/reset" endpoint? If you need example for creating controller, you can read [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/getting-started-first-application.html)

Comment: yes, my spring web application running under localhost with standard port(80) with web root servlet with path "/" and controller with "/reset" endpoint.i make the method in my controller and the view but i don't understand  how to combine with other .

Comment: in case you are trying to open the url even not from mail client and it is not still working, then it's not related to this question. Please create another topic and paste your code there so others can also find it. Here it can not be found by others and it is not comfortable to write comments without seeing any code :)